# Kill a spark action running in a Thread when it is stuck

Tags: java, multithreading, dataframe, apache-spark, caching

I have a java program which caches a hive table into memory using spark on a separate Thread. This Thread triggers periodically.
But sometimes, while running the action (count) after cache (when the actual caching happens) the job gets stuck.

I want to cancel/kill/stop this action if it is stuck.

I am trying to figure out how to do one of the 2 things below :

1. Kill this action if it takes more than 10 minutes.
2. OR Kill this when the Thread gets triggered again for next time (as Thread is getting triggered periodically).

Below is my code :

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    public void run(SparkSession spark) {

        Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.sql("select * from db.table");
        dataset.cache();

        // This is where job gets stuck sometimes. I want to kill/cancel this
        long count = dataset.count();

        System.out.println("Count = " + count);

    }
}
```

Comment: Fix the stucking......

Answer (score 0):

Your Thread got stuck because of Memory, you are using `cache()` method which  saves data to memory (`MEMORY_ONLY`)

1: try to use `persist(StorageLevel)` can cache in memory, on disk, or off-heap memory according to the caching strategy specified by level,

2: if you are running a job using spark-submit then  Kindly increase the  following parameters used while submitting the jobs

```
--num-executors 
--executor-cores  
--executor-memory 
--driver-memory
```